PrimeNG calendar time control 'AM'/'PM' localization
I'm using PrimeNG library in my Angular project.
And I am trying to localize time control 'AM'/'PM' values inside the calendar time control.
In the component I do next:
private primengConfig = inject(PrimeNGConfig);
ngOnInit() {
    this.primeNGConfig.setTranslation({
        am: 'a.m.',
        pm: 'p.m.'
    });
}

But I still see default 'AM'/'PM' in time control.
Then I went to check PrimeNG calendar original code inside, and I see that PrimeNG use translation only for aria-label and not for the other visible values:
original PrimeNG calendar code screenshot 1
original PrimeNG calendar code screenshot 2
Can someone help me to figure it out. Possibly I'm missing something or doing it incorretly.
Thanks.
